# typescript: access property with dot notation using 'dictionary' type

Tags: typescript

Trying to access a property of dict with dot notation makes Typescript complain. The language specification, 4.10, states:

> ObjExpr [ IndexExpr]
>
> ... if ObjExpr ’s apparent type has a string index signature and IndexExpr
> is of type Any, the String or Number primitive type, or an enum type, the property access is of the type of that index signature.

I am using:

```
interface MapStringToFunction {
  [index: string]: Function;
}

var dict: MapStringToFunction = {};

dict.say = () => 'hi';

dict.say();
```

MapStringToFunction has a sting index signature and `say` is of type String, so it should be allowed? But it obvious is not. What is my mistake and how can I change to code so I can type dict and access properties with dot notation?

Comment: This behavior surprises me as well. Even after reading the answer, I feel we should be able to reference property of interfaces with the dot notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For:

> the property access is of the type of that index signature

Property access in this case is the bracket notation:

```
interface MapStringToFunction {
  [index: string]: Function;
}

var dict: MapStringToFunction = {};

dict['say'] = () => 'hi';

dict['say']();
```

## More

The following will be a compile time error:

```
interface MapStringToFunction {
  [index: string]: Function;
  say: number; // Eroor
}
```

In our case, Function is the only property type that is allows:

```
interface MapStringToFunction {
  [index: string]: Function;
  say: Function;
}
```

However to be able to use any property it must be declared

Otherwise it would open up *too much* type-unsafe access. For example **if what you propose was allowed the following would only fail at runtime and not compile time**:

```
interface MapStringToFunction {
  [index: string]: Function;
}

var dict: MapStringToFunction = {};

dict.say() // Runtime error, as undefined is not callable
```

Comment: I seem to have a hard time understanding the concept of the dictionary pattern. In the example I mentioned, it there a way to define an interface for `dict` that allows for checking that the key should be String and the value Function? Or is var dict: any the best solution here?

Comment: key `string` is *always* allowed. The index signature only restricts what the *value* can be. 

That said I mostly use index signatures for documentation purposes, not type-safety.